# Google Cloud Storage Error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My application uses Google Cloud to upload the files. Following is my code :-

```
Storage.Objects.Insert requestObject;
requestObject = client.objects().insert(gcsAuthenticationInfo.getBucketName(), null , mediaContent);
requestObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
responseObject = requestObject.execute();
```

The moment `requestObject.execute();` actually executes application throws the following error. I could figure out that everything went fine until `ServerHelloDone`, but then client failed to parse the `ServerHelloDone` message. Here is the complete log that I could retrieve.

Please advise on how to resolve this issue.

```
[#|2014-09-26T09:18:30.823-0500|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-50001-5;_RequestID=362b2e8e-4223-4e3d-9248-eb633e55cf0e;|javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse key values
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:268)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.directUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:360)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:334)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.biperf.fsr.core.googlecloud.GoogleCloudUploadService.cloudUpload(GoogleCloudUploadService.java:84)
at com.biperf.fsr.ui.invoiceupload.FileUpload.upload(FileUpload.java:416)
at com.biperf.fsr.ui.invoiceupload.FileUpload.uploadRequest(FileUpload.java:153)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.biperf.fsr.core.servlet.FSRHomeContrInterceptor.intercept(FSRHomeContrInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.biperf.fsr.core.servlet.FSRServletInterceptor.intercept(FSRServletInterceptor.java:203)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MessageStoreInterceptor.intercept(MessageStoreInterceptor.java:197)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at com.objectpartners.cms.servlet.ContentReaderFilter.doFilter(ContentReaderFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at com.biperf.fsr.core.servlet.FoodServiceRewardsFilter.doFilter(FoodServiceRewardsFilter.java:403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at com.biperf.fsr.core.util.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.ee.web.sessmgmt.SessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(SessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:670)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:601)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:875)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:365)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:285)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:221)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:393)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:269)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse key values
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11ECPublicKey.fetchValues(P11Key.java:954)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11ECPublicKey.getW(P11Key.java:975)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ECDHClientKeyExchange.<init>(ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:40)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:782)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
... 135 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.
at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:544)
at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:347)
at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:277)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11ECPublicKey.fetchValues(P11Key.java:945)
... 144 more
|#]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the SSL exception, but it looks like you haven't set the object name or the content type, which will also cause problems. Do non-insert calls work for you?

Comment: Yes non-insert works for me. I was able to fetch the objects stored on Google Cloud under my application. Actually until sometime back even inserts were working fine without the above error. All of a sudden I am facing this SSL exception. I have downloaded the cert again from google developer console for my application, but no luck.